# C# Get dictionary from DLL

Tags: c#, dll, dictionary

I have class library project, where I have some methods and dictionaries

```
public static Dictionary<string, Instruments> globalInstruments;
public static Dictionary<string, WidgetInfo> _MinMaxStorageMinute;
public static Dictionary<string, WidgetInfo> _MinMaxStorageFive;
public static Dictionary<string, WidgetInfo> _MinMaxStorageFifteen;
public static Dictionary<string, WidgetInfo> _MinMaxStorageHalfHour;
public static Dictionary<string, WidgetInfo> _MinMaxStorageHour;
public static Dictionary<string, WidgetInfo> _MinMaxStorageFourHour;
public static Dictionary<string, WidgetInfo> _MinMaxStorageDay;
public static Dictionary<string, WidgetInfo> _MinMaxStorageWeek;
```

How can I get this dictionaries dynamically?
I try to do this

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\DFListener.dll");
Type type = asm.GetType("DFListener.Listener");
FieldInfo f = type.GetField("globalInstruments");
```

But how can I get access to dictionary values and keys?

EDIT

When I use same namespace I get this error

```
Additional information: [A]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,DFListener.Instruments] cannot be cast to [B]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,DFListener.Instruments]. Type A originates from 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' in the context 'LoadNeither' at location 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Type B originates from 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' in the context 'LoadNeither' at location 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'.`
```

Answer (score 2):

You're currently just getting the field - you need to get the *value* of the field using the [`GetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
var dictionary = (Dictionary<string, WidgetInfo>) f.GetValue(null);
```

Here the `null` argument is because it's a static field. If it were an instance field, you'd pass a target reference in, to specify the instance to get the value from.

Comment: I try it and getting error Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,DFListener.Instruments]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,ConsoleForTests.Instruments]'.

Comment: @Daedroth: Well you're clearly casting it to the wrong type - and neither of the types mentioned is the same as the type you've shown in your question...

Comment: How can I cast to the right type? I use same Instruments class.

Comment: @Daedroth: No, you don't - one class is `DFListener.Instruments`, the other is `ConsoleForTests.Instruments`. Those aren't the same classes at all - they're in different namespaces.